# Opening and executing python scripts on new terminal windows

Tags: python, macos, terminal, operating-system

I want to, from a python script, open a new terminal window.
Then, on that new window, run another python script, located on the same directory.
I needs to be on another window, because both scripts have while True loops, and I need them to run simultaneously.
How would I do that?
Thanks everyone!

Comment: Do you have any sample code so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can just spawn an xterm with the python code used:

```
xterm -e "python /path/to/your/file.py"
```

This will close when the process ends.

If you need to, you can do this from inside a python script using the subprocess module (https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).